# Retrieve current date without leading zeroes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date, nsdate, kal

I am trying to compare the date chosen on a calendar (Kal calendar implementation) with the current date. The issue is that the current date is in MM/dd/yyyy format, whereas the Kal dates will have no leading zeroes if the month or day is below 10. Is there an easy way to retrieve the current date so that it will not have leading zeroes for the day or month if it's under 10? (The current date will actually be utilized as an attribute for saved objects, so that they can later be queried using the date selected with Kal)

example current date - 07/07/2014

example Kal date - 7/7/2014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't compare strings holding dates. Create actual `NSDate` objects, using an `NSDateFormatter`, and compare those. The format strings you need are "MM/dd/yyyy" for your date, however you're retrieving it, and "M/d/yyyy" for Kal's date.

Answer (score 0):

I have used  **en_US_POSIX** along with **"MM/dd/yyyy"** & it's Working Fine

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7